# "kdeinit5 Closed Unexpectedly" twice after saving screenshot

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04

I recently upgraded to Kubuntu 21.04. Soon, i realised that after taking screenshots (using Spectacle) and saving them, i recieve this notification where kdeinit5 crashes.

The crash, occurs only when the notification tries to generate a thumbnail of the screenshot. So i guess it has something to do with thumbnail generation that is crashing kdeinit5.

This is the only time when such a crash occurs. I am not facing any crash elsewhere.

Here is the crash report.

```
Application: kdeinit5 (kdeinit5), signal: Segmentation fault

[KCrash Handler]
#4  __memcpy_ssse3_back () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-back.S:212
#5   in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#6   in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatch(int, QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#7   in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatchLoop() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#8   in kdemain () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#9   in ?? ()
#10  in ?? ()
#11  in ?? ()
#12  in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but it seems it was resolved on the latest KDE 5.81. Unfortunately, unless you add the backports repositoriy, you should wait for the 21.10 release.

Comment: I have added hirsute-backports, but currently there is *nothing* in there: https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute-backports/allpackages

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it works:

```
kdeinit5 --replace
```